# Creating an XML string in Flex (AS3) by using DOM functions

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, dom

I want to create an XML string in Flex 3 in a similar way to you might approach it in Java. I only want a small piece of XML in the format

```
<slide thumb="http://www.thumbs.com/thumb.jpg" type="static" blah="bleh" />
```

The only type of code I can find for doing this seems ridiculous....

```
private function createXML(): void
{
var xm:XML = <Relyon></Relyon>;
var nodeName:String = “EMPLOYEENAME”;
var nodeValue:String = “KUMAR”;
var xmlList:XMLList = XMLList(”<”+nodeName+”>”+nodeValue+”</”+nodeName+”>”);
xm.appendChild(xmlList);
Alert.show(xm);
}
```

I would like to do something like...

```
var x:XMLNode = new XMLNode("slide");
x.setAttribute("thumb", thumbURL);
x.setAttribute("type", "static");
```

This is surely possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Stay away from XMLNode if you're using as3, it's a legacy class, the new XML and XMLList classes are the ones that support the excellent E4X. Using those it's as easy as this:

```
var myXML:XML = <slide />;
myXML.@thumb="http://www.thumbs.com/thumb.jpg";
myXML.@type="static";
myXML.@blah="bleh";
trace("myXML", myXML.toXMLString());
```

The @ means it's an attribute, not using that would add child nodes instead.

Comment: I can't edit your answer, but I think you mean "attribute", not "property".

Comment: I would even remove the new XML entirely and just say:

var myXML:XML = <slide />;

Answer (score 1):

This would probably be easier:

```
var thumb:String = "http://www.thumbs.com/thumb.jpg";

var type:String = "static";

var blah:String = "bleh";

var xml:XML =        

          <Relyon>
             <slide thumb={thumb} type={type} blah={blah} />
          </Relyon>;


trace( xml.toXMLString() );

//traces out

 <Relyon>
     <slide thumb="http://www.thumbs.com/thumb.jpg" type="static" blah="bleh"/>
 </Relyon>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are using a variable as the attribute name you can use

```
var _attName:String = "foo";
myXML.@[_attName] = "bar";
```

but you would need to read it back out as

```
myXML.@[_attname][0];
```